# Gradle sync failed while creating android app in intellij 16

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm using Intellij IDEA 2016.3.4 on ubuntu 14.04 LTS to develop android applications. An error- `gradle sync failed, missing android extension is occurring.`

I'm using sdk platform 25.0.2, kotlin version 1.0.6. This is the line that is throwing an error:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

and the error message is:

> Error:(16, 0) Extension with name 'android' does not exist. Currently registered extension names: [ext]
>   Open File

I'm lost. Please can anyone help me out. A detailed solution would be much appreciated!

EDIT 1: Here is the build.gradle code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

defaultConfig {

    applicationId "com.example.gogol.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}

buildTypes {

    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {

  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0',  {
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
 })

  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

EDIT 2: here is build.gradle root project

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {

ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.6'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'

    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong

    // in the individual module build.gradle files

}
  }

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}

repositories {    
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version" 
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.1'
}

android {
  sourceSets {

    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
  }

  compileSdkVersion 25
  buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
 }
```

Comment: Have you added the kotlin plugin in IntelliJ - I'm not sure if that's got anything to do with it but it's worth a try

Comment: yeah, kotlin plugin is enabled. I've the recent version as well.

Comment: Do you have `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` in `build.gradle`?

Comment: thanks for that, @CrazyCoder. That plugin is there, what I found out was android.support:appcompat-v7 has version 24.1.1. I've Google support repository installed. where'll i get 25.1.1? nothing as such is there in sdk manager.

Comment: @DebadriChowdhury Could you provide you build.gradle code please?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan , build.gradle has been added

Comment: @DebadriChowdhury this is your app module build.gradle file, please provide  your build.gradle of your root  project.

Comment: build.gradle root project has been added. @AbhishekAryan

Answer (score 1):

Add `apply plugin: 'android'` in your root build.gradle file.

After that your build.gradle file looks like

```
buildscript {

  ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.6'

  repositories {
      jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}

repositories {    
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version" 
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.1'
}

android {

  sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
  }

  compileSdkVersion 25
  buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
}
```